# calling a method by class level annotated with @RequestMapping that includes an autowired class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, request-mapping, class-level

I am trying to call a method that is annotated with `@RequestMapping`(signIn) through a class level (from method: authentication) like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = /authenticate, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response authentication(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    UserController user = new UserController();     
    return user.signIn(request, null);
}
```

and my controller looks like:

```
@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;

@RequestMapping(value = /signin, method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public @ResponseBody Response signIn(HttpServletRequest request) {      
        JsonObject json = Misc.parseJson(request);
        String lang = Misc.getLang(request);
        user.setEmail(Misc.getEmail(json));
        user.setPassword(Misc.getEncryptedPassword(json));

        return ResponseUtils.success(userManager.auth(user, lang));

}
```

user manager is annotated with @component:

```
   @Component
   public class UserManager {
        public User auth(User user, String lang) {
         ....
        return user;
       }
   }
```

Problem is when I call the method "signIn" and just new-up a UserController instance through "/authenticate" mapping, the UserManager becomes NULL. So now I'm assuming that autowiring doesn't work when it's done this way.

Is there any other way to call the signIn method? I would hate to copy paste an already existing code to another class just to get this to work...

Comment: Why are you instantiating a controller class inside another controller class? Show your UserManager code, is it spring-managed? For authentication and authorization, I would recommend using Spring-Security, rather than creating your own.

Comment: We need to authenticate some actions like deleting or updating certain data in our site, even if the user is already logged in. And so I figured that instead of creating another authentication checking, I could just use the method being used for logging in a user into the site since it's basically the same. I figured I can't use the same mapping for this, or is there a way to create two mapping values for a single method?

Comment: If its a service layer method, you can create any number of methods in controller with different mapping values or the URL. your authentication code is unknown, what you are trying to achieve doesn't seem to be normal, please read spring documentation first.

Comment: alright thanks for the help We are Borg. I'll check on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I just separated the logic instead. Though one solution that I tried and I could have used was to just add another mapping to the signIn method instead of adding a new method in the other class since the logic was similar. Still I opted for a separate logic instead since there were a lot of unnecessary code in the signIn method for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Autowiering only works in spring managed bean. If you create a class with `new` keyword, it is not a spring managed bean and autowiering would not work.

You can try to autowire the class which contains the method which is annotated or better put the code in a service class which can be used by both methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem with @Autowired .There are two type of Annotation 
firstly method base annotation and field level annotation. You just used field level annotation.Check your import class with "org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired" or it can be problem with initiation of "UserManager"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you not moving logic into separate Service classs, but try this:

UserController.java

```
public UserController(UserManager userManager) {
    this.userManager = userManager;
}
```

and then inside controller where authentication resource method is located:

```
@Autowired UserManager userManager;

@RequestMapping(value = /authenticate, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response authentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    UserController user = new UserController(userManager);
    return user.signIn(request);
}
```